# How do I edit the layer mask selection using the adjustments tab?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photography

I have two layer images imported from lightroom, one underexposed for the background sunset and one overexposed for the subject. How do I make adjustments to the layer mask selection itself without it effecting the entire layer image? I would like to get it exposed just right in Photoshop first before doing Lightroom edits, if possible.

**PS Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is Clipping Mask. Create your Adjustment Layer directly above whatever layer you want it applied to then hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click between the two layers in your layer panel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you goal is (mind explaining a little more what you need to do?), but here's something you can try from what I think your goal is.

Here's your normal set up as of now:

[image]

- Two images (one overexposed and one underexposed)
- The top image has a layer mask. In your post you have **make adjustments to the layer mask selection itself without it effecting the entire layer image**

To do that you can just make the Layer Mask a selection in your image by **right clicking** over the layer mask and choosing **Add Mask to Selection** (or using a cool shortcut, in Windows it's by pressing Ctrl key and clicking on layer mask).

[image]

The result is:

[image]

Now any changes you apply to the image will only affect the part that is selected.

[image]

I don't really  know if this is what you want because even if you did make adjustment to the **whole** image, it would be ok because the layer mask is only going to show the part you want. In my example, the girl, in yours I think it's the background.

Hope this helps set you in the right path.